# Linux DD Command: How to extract files from an ISO image?

Tags: linux, images, fedora, extract

I need to extract the OS filesystem from Fedora's ISO image (downloadable from their site) using dd command?

Comment: You need to extract an specific file?

Comment: this is vague. One can not extract a filesystem from an image, a filesystem isn't data.

Answer (score 12):

If you already have the ISO filesystem in a file on your hard drive (downloaded from the Internet or copied, wholesale, from a CD or DVD), you'll need to mount the file in "loopback" mode. ("loopback" means the source of the filesystem is in fact another file, not a physical device.) As root, something like this would work:

```
# mkdir /tmp/fedora
# mount /path/to/image.iso /tmp/fedora -o ro,loop -t iso9660
```

Then you can browse /tmp/fedora using your favorite tools.

You can use `dd` to create an iso file from a CD or DVD:

```
# dd if=/dev/cdrom of=image.iso
```

Comment: maybe he was wondering if he could burn the ISO to a DVD using dd?

Answer (score 6):

I believe `dd` can't do that, it just enables raw access to the ISO file itself.

I think you should use the `mount` command:

```
mount -o loop file.iso /mnt
```

Answer (score 3):

[How to mount an ISO image under Linux](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-to-mount-iso-image-under-linux.html)